# In Django, the HTML code is shown instead of the actual text

Tags: python, django

& g t ; Welcome

How do I show the actual symbol instead? Is it a template filter?

Thanks.

Comment: Redit question, be more precise or give us some example what u would achieve...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bit hard to know without more details. If it's from data that you're passing in from the view, you might want to use `mark_safe`.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def your_view(request):
    ...
    foo = '&gt;'
    mark_safe(foo)
    ...
```

Otherwise, you want the [`safe`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter:

```
{{ myvar|safe }}
```

Obviously, be careful with this, make sure the variable *actually is safe*, otherwise you'll open yourself up to cross-site scripting attacks and the like. There's a reason Django escapes this stuff.